# How to activate Zen Coding completions inside Handlebars templates using Sublime Text 2

Tags: handlebars.js, emmet, sublimetext2

I have installed Zen Coding for Sublime Text 2. It works while expanding abbreviations outside of the  tags, but it does not inside those script tags (which makes sense since js is expected there). However, it would be useful while editing Handlebars templates.

Does anyone know, how to configure/modify Zen Coding ST2 plugin to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The command it's now called `expand_abbreviation_by_tab` (I'm using Sublime Text 3).

In order to use Emmet inside the embedded js (the x-handlebars script scope) just paste this command inside your keymap file `Key Bindings — User`:

```
{
    "keys": [
        "tab"
    ],
    "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab",
    "context": [
        {
            "operand": "source.js.embedded.html",
            "operator": "equal",
            "match_all": true,
            "key": "selector"
        }
    ]
}
```

Add whichever scope you need Emmet to work as a *value* of the **`operand`** key.

*Best of all you don't need to restart Sublime. It start working right away!*

Answer (score 4):

In `./ZenCoding/Default.sublime-keymap` there is a set of context scope selectors that define what actions are active when editing different portions of the file. These are the same [scope selectors that TextMate uses](http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors).

The default scope for the `expand_zen_abbreviation_on_tab` command (at the time of writing this it's the last entry in the file) does not include a selector for `<script>` tags. We need to add it.

In order to find the correct scope, place your cursor somewhere in a ST2 document and hit `ctrl+shift+p`. The status bar will show you the selectors for the region you're in. In the case of a script tag saved in a .html file, it returns:

```
text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html
```

Given this information, we add the `source.js.embedded.html` entry to the `operand` property of the `expand_zen_abbreviation_on_tab` command and voilà, zen coding will work inside script tags.

**Here is my `expand_zen_abbreviation_on_tab` with the  context added...**

```
 {"command": "expand_zen_abbreviation_on_tab",
  "context": [{"key": "selector",
               "match_all": true,
               "operand": "source.css - source.css.embedded, text.xml, text.html -source -meta.tag, meta.scope.between-tag-pair.html -source, source.js.embedded.html",
               "operator": "equal"},
              {"key": "selection_empty",
               "match_all": true,
               "operand": true,
               "operator": "equal"},
              {"key": "is_zen", "match_all": true}],
  "keys": ["tab"]}]
```

Comment: Do you if this feature has been added to Zen Coding/Emmet to allow use inside a script area?

Answer (score 0):

at line 31 of “zencoding/zen_settings.py” change 'filters': 'html,css', to 'filters': 'html,css,hbs' can also add other file types here as well such as erb if you are using rails.